# Mapping CoreGraphics Blend Modes to Porter-Duff

Tags: iphone, android, core-graphics, blending, porter-duff

I have an iPhone app that does image manipulation via blending two `UIImage` objects via CoreGraphics, specifically `CGContextSetBlendMode`. I am currently researching porting it to Android. I've gone through the process of combining to `Bitmap` objects on Android using PorterDuff modes. However, I want much more complicate compositing. For example, I'm using `kCGBlendModeHardLight` for many blends:

> Either multiplies or screens colors,
>   depending on the source image sample
>   color. If the source image sample
>   color is lighter than 50% gray, the
>   background is lightened, similar to
>   screening. If the source image sample
>   color is darker than 50% gray, the
>   background is darkened, similar to
>   multiplying. If the source image
>   sample color is equal to 50% gray, the
>   source image is not changed. Image
>   samples that are equal to pure black
>   or pure white result in pure black or
>   white. The overall effect is similar
>   to what you’d achieve by shining a
>   harsh spotlight on the source image.
>   Use this to add highlights to a scene.

But don't know of anyway (if it's even possible) to emulate this via Porter-Duff. Does Android not support better Image Manipulation algorithms out of the box? Is it possible to use Porter-Duff in some way to emulate more advanced blend modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the 12 Porter-Duff blending equations, Android supports Lighten, Darken, Multiply, Screen and soon Overlay. Unfortunately this means HardLight is not available and you would have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (although not the one I was hoping for).